how to change species name font size in co-occurrence matrix in R
Tried to change the font size. Here's my current output

This is species co-occurrence matrix in R.
I tried many ways to change the species name font size, doesn't work.
If anyone know how to change, please help. Thanks in advance.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What packages are you using?

It's a ggplot object. The object you want to change the size of can be modified using the geom_text() function. However, for this to work, you have to modify the source function plot.cooccur() that comes with the package.

Step 1: Make sure to load the dependencies of the package {cooccur}: {ggplot2},{gmp},{reshape2}
Step 2: Go to the GitHub repository of the package and copy the script of the plot.cooccur() function. Copy all of it and then place it in a new R script within your environment. GitHub link of the function.
Step 3: Locate line 140. That's where you need to change the size of the text.

p <- p + geom_text(data=dfids,aes(label=X1),hjust=1,vjust=0,angle = -22.5, size = 15) #Here you can change the size argument


Step 4:  Return to the first line and run the complete function. It will appear in your global environment as a new global function plot.coocur().
Final Step: You can go back to your dataset and plot the object using that function:

library(cooccur)
data(finches)
cooccur.finches <- cooccur(finches,
                          type = "spp_site",
                          thresh = TRUE,
                          spp_names = TRUE)
class(cooccur.finches)

x <- plot.cooccur(cooccur.finches) 
x

# It also works with plot(), but it's better this way to not interfere with other dependencies


Hope it helps.
PS: As MrFlick mentioned, it's easier for others to assist you if you include a reproducible example next time.
